# Drupal installation issue. GD and PDO unrecognized

Tags: drupal, ubuntu, pdo, amazon-ec2, gd

sorry if this has been answered already, but my searches brought me to nowhere.

I have just installed LAMP environment on Amazon EC2 instance. It runs on:

```
Ubuntu precise 12.04 amd64 server
PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4
MySQL 5.5.28
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Drupal 7-18
```

Drupal installation tells me that I have not GD enabled and PDO extension are disabled. However, looking at phpinfo() I have :

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.0
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.4.8
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version unknown
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.46
WBMP Support    enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning  0   0
```

and

```
PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  5.5.28

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

So, in theory everything must work, why does Drupal not recognize them? I haven't changed anything at all from the clean install of LAMP. May I be missing something then?

Thanks in advance,
maxim

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the problem was solved with reinstalling:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-gd php5-mysql
```